# Determine if a directory contains a file

Tags: java

I have `java.io.File` objects A and B, where A represents a directory and B represents a file. B can be an absolute path or a relative path that is 0 or more levels below A. what's the most efficient way to determine if B is contained by A?

For example,

A is C:\Users\bill\Desktop\abc\xyz123 and B is C:\Users\bob\Documents\inc\data.inc

or

A is C:\Users\bill\Desktop\abc\xyz123 and B is C:\Users\bob\Documents\x1\y1\inc\data.inc

or

A is C:\Users\bill\Desktop\abc\xyz123 and B is ..\..\..\Documents\inc\data.inc

Comment: Come on, dude...it's right in the `File` API - [`getParentFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()).

Comment: Please think of this site as somewhere to go when you are stuck, not before you begin.

Comment: Perhaps I over simplified the example.

Comment: Do you want to check if B is directly below A or in any folder under A? Either way, you should be able to use getParentFile() and looping to get the result

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check to see if A is the parent of B by doing

```
A.equals(B.getParentFile())
```

Edit: If you want to check if B is one or more levels below A, just keep getting the ParentFile until it's A or null

```
File C = B.getParentFile();

while(C != null) {
    if(A.equals(C))
        return true;

    C = C.getParentFile();
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`getParentFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29), which returns the parent directory, and [`getCanonicalFile()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalFile%28%29) can be of use. Like so:

```
File bDir = b.getParentFile();
boolean same = bDir.equals(a) || bDir.getCanonicalFile().equals(a.getCanonicalFile());
```

Paths can be tricky. If you're lucky the just `getParent()` is all that's necessary. Using `getCanonicalFile()` should cover the more complicated cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class FileUtils:

```
public static boolean directoryContains(File directory,
                                        File child)
                                 throws IOException
```

*Determines whether the parent directory contains the child element (a file or directory).*